# ping6: How to use the "-b" option

Tags: linux, ping, ipv6

What is the purpose of `ping6 -b` and how do I make use of it? The `man` page says *Allow pinging a broadcast address*. Since there is no broadcast in IPv6, I'm puzzled.

I'm using:

```
Host> ping6 -V
ping6 utility, iputils-sss20101006
Host>
```

Comment: Um, I got a `ping6: invalid option -- 'b'` message when I tried to run `ping6 -b` Seems like the `b` switch for ping6 doesn't work. I think if it exists, it would be to ping the _multicast address_

Comment: Broadcasting still exists in IPv6, but only within a particular scope. There are three multicast addresses for that purpose - FF01::1, FF02::1, FF05::1. Site-local multicasting is not deprecated. However, I can use them as a destination address without the need for a broadcast switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely a documentation glitch. As you correctly say, there's no broadcast addresses on IPv6 so this option will probably be removed from documentation in future releases.

```
# ping6 -b ::1
ping6: invalid option -- 'b'
```